# Configure Webpack output bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Im new to React development with Webpack having set up a boilerplate by following this [tutorial article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/).

I get the jist of how webpack works and can follow along with the article but having trouble understanding how my particular `webpack.config.js` is creating the files and bundles that it does and how to modify these to achieve some custom function.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ],
  mode: 'development'
};
```

I understand that the `rules` object grabs all `.js` files (excluding those in node_modules) and compiles them to standard JS using babel. Then it grabs all the `.html` files and creates an html file including the bundle using `html-loader`. The `HtmlWebPackPlugin` is implemented here. Mode indicates to create a development version of the bundle.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
- /dist (generated by webpack)
    - index.html
    - main.js (webpack bundle)
- /src (created manually)
  - /components
    - components.js (react components)
  - index.html
  - index.js
- .babelrc
- package.json (npm init -y)
- webpack.config.js (manually configured)
```

**Questions:**

1. Webpack creates the `/dist` directory and the files contained in it. Where in the configuration is it indicated that this directory be named "dist" and the main bundle file be named `main.js`?
2. Where is it indicated that `/dist` be at the root of the project. Suppose I wanted the directory to be named `foo` and placed two levels up (`../../foo/`)
3. In `webpack.config.js` the "rules" object has keys defined as `test` to indicate which files types to bundle. `test: /\.js$/,` & `test: /\.html$/` Is "test" an arbitrary value or a default webpack configuration key.

I was looking at [these](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) docs with regard to webpack configuration but the syntax was very different from what is shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 & 2:**

you can set output config like this:

```
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
```

- filename

name of output bundle file. *default: main.js*

- path

  location of save output files. *default: /dist*

to get root of project you have to use path!

import path:

```
var path = require('path');
```

and use like this:

```
path.resolve(__dirname, DIRECTORY_NAME)
```

**3:**
test is default webpack configuration key and its to specify that loader file type support like `html-loader`.